# determine the area under the hyperbola $y^2 −4x^2 = 1$

Tags: conic-sections, arc-length

Show that to find the length of an arc of the parabola $y = x^2$ one needs to determine the area under the hyperbola $y^2−4x^2 = 1$.

I solved for y and got $y=\sqrt {1+4x^2}$

But I really don't know what I am doing.

Comment: What is the context of this problem? Is it from a calculus class, geometry class, etc.?

Comment: It's from a History of Math class. We are in a calculus section

Comment: The title is somewhat misleading, since the area "under" the hyperbola cannot be determined without setting bounds on $x$ in some way.  Since a hyperbola (or "an hyperbola" if you prefer) extends to infinity in both directions along its asymptotes, no finite area is defined by the hyperbola alone.  However when we read the body of the text, what is really at issue is connecting two integrations:  the arc length of the parabola with the "area" integral of a hyperbola.  That makes sense as an exercise (really just setting up and simplifying the arc length integral).

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Sorry about the confusion!

Answer (score 2):

The starting point is that the [arc lenght](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Finding_arc_lengths_by_integrating) of a smoot curve of equation $y=f(x)$ from $x=a$ to $x=b$ is 
$$
s=\int_a^b\sqrt{1+(y'(x))^2}
dx$$

so, for the arc lenght of the given parabola we have:
$$
s=\int_a^b\sqrt{1+(2x)^2}
dx$$

on the other side   the  positive branch of the given hyperbola is given by the equation:
$$
y=\sqrt{1+4x^2}
$$
so the area delimited by this curve and the $x-$ axis betveen $x=a$ and $x=b$ is:
$$
A= \int_a^b\sqrt{1+4x^2}dx
$$

and the two integrals a re the same.

Answer (score 2):

The formula of arc length of the function $y=f(x)$ where $x\in[a,b]$ is 
$$
arc\ length=\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}\,dx
$$
In your case $f(x)=x^2$, so $f'(x)=2x$. Therefore
$$
arc\ length=\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{1+(2x)^2}\,dx
=\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{1+4x^2}\,dx
$$
which is the area under $y^2-4x^2=1$ in the interval $[a,b]$.